# How to send values from one view to other View in eclipse e4?

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I am using pure eclipse e4 application. I have created one handler and two parts. Using the handler I selected the files and displayed in one of the part say "Part A". The Part A has a tableviewer with checkboxes. After selecting particular files from the table viewer checkbox , I need to calculate some values from those selected files and display them in some kind of graph in the second part say Part B. I need the selected files in Part B so that I can process those files and using Jfreechart I can display the chart in Part B.

My question is how to pass values from Part A to Part B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the e4 Event Broker to do this.

In the part that wants to send events inject the event broker:

```
@Inject
private IEventBroker eventBroker;
```

To send data asynchronously use:

```
eventBroker.post("base_topic/data_event", data);
```

to send synchronously use:

```
eventBroker.send("base_topic/data_event", data);
```

In your part that wants to receive the data use:

```
@Inject
@Optional
void dataEvent(@EventTopic("base_topic/data_event") DataType data)
```

if you want the data to be received on the UI thread use `@UIEventTopic` instead of `@EventTopic`.

The event topic names are something you decide on, I have just used an example here.

Note: Since this uses injection the code must be in something like an `MPart` class (or you must do the injection yourself).

More details [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html)